# Decimal constructor throws System.ArgumentException when I pass int array of 4 elements

Tags: c#, .net

I have an array of 4 `unsigned int` entries of the same value `255` I would like to convert them into a `decimal` value. Here is the code:

```
public static decimal BytesToDecimal(byte[] buffer, int offset = 0)
{
    var decimalBits = new int[4];

    decimalBits[0] = buffer[offset + 0] | (buffer[offset + 1] << 8) | (buffer[offset + 2] << 16) | (buffer[offset + 3] << 24);
    decimalBits[1] = buffer[offset + 4] | (buffer[offset + 5] << 8) | (buffer[offset + 6] << 16) | (buffer[offset + 7] << 24);
    decimalBits[2] = buffer[offset + 8] | (buffer[offset + 9] << 8) | (buffer[offset + 10] << 16) | (buffer[offset + 11] << 24);
    decimalBits[3] = buffer[offset + 12] | (buffer[offset + 13] << 8) | (buffer[offset + 14] << 16) | (buffer[offset + 15] << 24);

    return new decimal(decimalBits);
 }

static void Main(string[] args)
{           
    decimal dd = BytesToDecimal(new byte[16] { 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255 });
     Console.WriteLine("{0}", dd.ToString());           
 }
```

I expect the result `-1`; however, the program throws the following exception.

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Decimal byte array
>   constructor requires an array of length four containing val id decimal
>   bytes.

Comment: Is this part of any cross-platform code? To my knowledge, the internal representation of `System.Decimal` is not portable.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the constructor documentation for `decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.decimal.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7#System_Decimal__ctor_System_Int32___), bits 0 through 15, and 24 through 30, of the fourth int array element must all be zero. 255, as an 8-bit binary number, is all ones. So you're feeding the constructor an array of ints that have every bit set to 1.

Comment: You cannot pass arbitrary int arrays through to this constructor, it's intended for the output of decimal.GetBits method. If you want to pass in your own int arrays you have to read the documentation for the decimal type & understand how it encodes its data. It's not a simple exponents followed by addition algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the assumption that if you set all bits of a decimal, the result will be -1. This is not how decimals are stored.

Your method would be correct for integers, but not for a fixed point number like a decimal. A decimal does not only store the base number (the. mantissa), but also the position of the decimal dot. Also, the sign is set differently in a decimal, since the mantissa is unsigned.

Check [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348938/vb-c-decimal-internal-format) for further information on how to format a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [Decimal(Int32[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1de0ya1(v=vs.110).aspx) last array element used as flag.

> bits [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits(v=vs.110).aspx) contains the scale factor and sign, and consists of following parts:
>
> Bits 0 to 15, the lower word, are unused and must be zero.
>
> Bits 16 to 23 must contain an exponent between 0 and 28, which indicates the power of 10 to divide the integer number.
>
> Bits 24 to 30 are unused and must be zero.
>
> Bit 31 contains the sign; 0 meaning positive, and 1 meaning negative.

Integer value *-1* in binary format `Convert.ToString(-1, 2);` equals to

*11111111111111111111111111111111*

And this value doesn't match

```
private const int SignMask  = unchecked((int)0x80000000);
```

or

```
private const int ScaleMask = 0x00FF0000;
```

masks, that is why in [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs,285) when you pass -1, condition

```
(f & ~(SignMask | ScaleMask)) == 0 && (f & ScaleMask) <= (28 << 16))
```

returns *false* and the next command throw the exception.

---

**Update**

if you wish to find out how value -1 represents in Decimal you could use [Decimal.GetBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
string.Join(" ", decimal.GetBits((decimal) -1))
```

Result will be:

> 1 0 0 -2147483648

[.netFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kQEbYq)